# Linux Socket and ARP spoofing

Tags: linux, sockets, ip, arp, raw-sockets

I have been experimenting with ARP spoofing on my local LAN.
Now, I would like to try to write in C a simple sniffer, but I have some questions:

1. If the ARP spoofing has been a success my NIC will receive and not drop packets that have my MAC ADDRESS (Layer 2) but a DST IP (Layer 3) which is not mine. What kind of sockets can I use to take those packets? I think some sort of RAW sockets, but an example or a good reference would be appreciated.
2. Is there a way (throw C) to put my NIC in promiscuous mode in order to force it to pick up packets with different MAC?

Comment: Promiscuous mode support is a proprietary capability of NIC driver/FW. Refer to the product documentation.

Comment: Er, no, that's not correct. While NICs differ in minute details, pretty much every NIC supports promiscuous mode, and there are standard mechanisms for enabling it that don't require looking at NIC documentation. I would start with `libpcap` (http://www.tcpdump.org/). You may end up needing to use an `AF_PACKET` socket directly for more advanced operations, but not for just sniffing traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I think the best way is to use libcap http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/libcap.3.html, which comes with good routine to call.